# Pipe every bash output to file

Tags: ruby, bash

Is there a way to pipe every output to a file, like monitoring the terminal to make a history of everything that is printed?

Also, when I use `tee` it seems to stop the output of the actual program. How can I change this? I want to maintain the normal output and just use a copy of it to save in the file.

Just as an example, I have this ruby script:

```
100.times do |i|
  puts i
end
```

And running `$ruby script.rb | tee output.txt` will save the output just fine, but it will only be printed after the whole thing runs.

Comment: The reason it's only printing after the whole thing runs is that `tee` is buffering it internally. If you were just running it normally, the standard output stream would get flushed after every line, but tee has in internal buffer and only flushes to stdout when that gets sufficiently full. You would find that if you ran 100000.times do |i| instead, that it would print before it was done running. Just FYI

Comment: `man script` may help you. Good luck.

Comment: `script` seems to be the solution. I'll look into it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Doing It With Bash

If you're using bash (which you are according to your tags), you could run `script -a -c "ruby your_script.rb" -f your_file.out`.

So, for example, if you wrote the following script, saved it as `test.rb`:

```
# test.rb
i = 0
while true do
    i += 1
    puts i
    sleep 1
end
```

And then ran `script -a -c "ruby test.rb" -f test.out`, you'd be able to refresh the file every time and see that it is incrementing one by one each second, even though the script is *in media res*; that is, still running. This is because it is "flushing" every output.

**DRAWBACKS:** You can only do this using the `script` command in bash. In this regard, you create a dependency; if `script` is not there, or it does not work as the `script` on my machine does, then this approach might not work at all. Always be wary of dependencies.

## Doing It In Ruby Itself

Sometimes, you might not be running your script on bash and `script` may not be available. What then? Well, you can just create a method that prints to a file and then to the stdout, regardless of operating system. It will then flush the file every time to make sure it's up-to-date.

```
# print_to_file.rb
class PrintOutputToFile
  def self.file
    @@file ||= File.open("my_output.log", "w")
  end

  def self.puts! some_data
    file.write "#{some_data}\n"
    file.flush
    puts some_data
  end
end

i = 0
while true do
  i += 1
  PrintOutputToFile.puts! i
  sleep 1
end
```

**DRAWBACKS:** This will clear the file every time you run it. You might need to modify this little script if you want to keep a long-term log that saves over many runs. Also, this script will crash outright if you do not have file permissions. This is ***not*** meant to be used for production, but merely as a proof-of-concept for those interested in implementing a system like this.

## Another Way To Do It In Ruby Itself

You can also do this by copying the old puts method into a proc, and then overriding the core puts method to write to the log file, but ending it with an invocation of the original puts method.

```
@@old_puts = method(:puts).to_proc
def puts(output)
  @@file ||= File.open("your_log.txt", "w")
  @@file.write "#{output}\n"
  @@old_puts.call output
  @@file.flush
end
```

**DRAWBACKS:** This is a step beyond hacky and I frankly would not recommend actually doing this unless you really, really know what you're doing and absolutely have to.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking the time to help.
`script` does what I want, but I can't seem to start it from inside a .sh script (so I can run it automatically). I keep getting `command not found` when running:
`#!/bin/bash
 $(script -f log.txt)`

Comment: Of course. I just edited the post to colorize the text correctly. Does this explain how to go about solving your problem satisfactorily?

Comment: Did you `chmod u+x whatever.sh` and make sure that you made the format for script `script -a -c "ruby whatever.rb" -f log.txt` in your shell script?

Comment: Almost there. I need to use it every time I start a terminal. Can I do that?

Comment: Sort of. That ties it to a specific script, which is not quite what I want. I need it to log everything that happens.

Comment: I put in a third approach to this problem. Hopefully it serves your ends.

Comment: Hey, Luke. Your first approach was what I needed, but I did some improvements that maybe will interest you: I put the call to `script` inside the .bashrc file. Doing that by itself creates an infinite loop because of the way `script` works, so you need to make sure that you call it only once. A simple if statement using `$SHLVL == 1` will do. Now I get to log everything that happens on the shell automatically. Thank you very much for helping me out.